# Outputting a GD image direct to the browser creates an error

Tags: php

Ok feeling a bit dumb here. I am obviously missing something super basic but I am not sure what.

I have created several images in php using imagejpeg which work just fine and I can store the images ready for use in another file.

But if I want to create an image and output it directly to the browser all in one go I get the following error

> The image "http://localhost/myProject/sandbox/myImageResize.php"
>   cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

This error is output by firefox but fire bug reports no errors Under images it reports status 200 OK.. which wikipedia states is...

> 200 OK Standard response for successful HTTP requests. The actual
>   response will depend on the request method used. In a GET request, the
>   response will contain an entity corresponding to the requested
>   resource. In a POST request the response will contain an entity
>   describing or containing the result of the action

It doesn't matter if I use imagejpeg or imagepng or imagegif. The result is always the same.

I have got output buffering set to on and I am not outputting anything before the header.

```
//send image to browser
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($im, NULL, 90);
imagedestroy($im);
```

I can file the same image just fine. I can pick up that same image and display it in the browser from another php file. So the error message which states that there are errors in the image doesn't ring true.

I am assuming the output buffering being set to on applies to images just like anything else. So even if I had output something ahead of the header it wouldn't matter or have I misunderstood this?

There must be an answer but I am at a loss to what it is.

Note in other browsers the image simply fails to display.

Up to now it hasn't been an issue because I just handle the image in two steps. But I now want output a captcha image directly to the browser so I really need to understand what is going wrong.

Kind Regards

Ok not sure of ettiquette here. But adding further findings here.

Firstly sometime during the hunt for this problem I made things worse by introducing a typo in that a font had a typo in it in one of the php files I was having a problem with. The error was located in apache/logs/error.log.

Secondly also located in apache/logs/error.log I found PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent. This totally confused me as I know that I had set output buffering on using integer value 4096 in php.ini.

The offending header came from an include:

```
<?php
    function redirect_To($location = NULL){
        if ($location != NULL ){
            header("Location: {$location}");
            exit;
        }
    }

?>
```

Now it is an *assumption* that during the evaluate stage of the include that header was output to the buffer. If some one could confirm that that is a correct assumption I would be grateful. The function was not in fact called at all in the test run that created the problem so this assumption is my only explanation of this behaviour.

Now this itself should not have created an issue since buffering was set to on and it appeared (erroneously as it turned out) that nothing else was being output until the header associated with the imagejpeg statement.

What I now tentatively conclude was occurring was that as I put the image through intermediate gd functions before arriving at the image I wanted and that these functions used the output buffer and pushed the header from the include out. Temporarily removing the interim gd functions produced a positive result.

However my conclusion falls apart, hence tentative, because I thought ok set output-buffering = On in php.ini which should set the buffer to unlimited and so the first header should not get pushed out. But no joy back to the same old error.

So I can work around this. But I can't say that I fully understand why the header from the include is being pushed out.

Regards

Further (final note) note:

I got drawn into looking at the include functions because of log entry:

```
[Tue Aug 21 22:44:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ampps\\www\\CCC_OOP_V1\\sandbox\\upload.php:106) in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ampps\\www\\CCC_OOP_V1\\_includes\\functions.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/CCC_OOP_V1/sandbox/test_Image_Proportional_Resize.php
```

But using headers sent:

```
<?php require_once("../_includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
    if (headers_sent($filename, $linenum)){
        echo "Require once output headers in " . $filename ." at " . $linenum;
    } else {
        echo "no headers sent";
    }
?>
```

No headers were sent. Therefore the route I was following yesterday is a complete dead end. I remain confused by the log entry.

I have to admit defeat and confess that I do not understand. The following

```
if (headers_sent($filename, $linenum)){
        echo "Require once output headers in " . $filename ." at " . $linenum;
            exit;
    } else {
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");  // tmp code to output to browser
        imagejpeg($new, NULL, 90);                      // tmp code to output to browser
    }
```

produces error

The image "http://localhost/myProject/sandbox/myImageResize.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

But obviously no headers have been output. No other errors are sent to the log.

So I have a solution (split the code out). But I still lack understanding.

Comment: What does the output look like when you use curl to download it from the command line?

Comment: @Rich sorry I am not familiar with that expression what is curl?

Comment: That's OK. Can you post a link to the script on line and I'll have a look. Curl is just a tool for downloading stuff, it comes built into to most operating systems, but isn't on Windows by default.

Comment: @Rich Ok that was a complete disaster. installing Curl on windows installed a shed load of malware. Some rubbish call Internet Turbo Community Tool Bar hijacked chrome and FF and conduit search engine hijacked chrome. So 3 hours later having removed it and having had to completely uninstall and reinstall chrome I'm back. But I ain't going anywhere near anything called CURL. I am going to run a complete scan in a moment which will take several hours and run my cleaner and hope to God I've got rid of it all. So Thx but another way will have to be found.

Comment: What? This is why people don't use Windows. If you are going into web development, it's a key tool. I'd advise you to get yourself set up with this sort of basic tool. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL is what I'm talking about. http://curl.haxx.se/download.html actually has the Windows binaries ready to download. Anyway, what's the link, I might be able to tell you why it's not working.

Comment: @Rich Thx I have realised that I have two problems. The first is an easy fix. imagettftext had a font misspelt. So that's sorted. But the trickiness is as I suspected the headers.